# Swift - Printing out the current value of a number

Tags: ios, swift, counter

I'm currently developing a counter app which every time you press a button it will count up. I have already done this and works 100%, what I'm trying to do is make a another button and when you press it, it shows the current number on the console but it only prints out `0` because that's the default variable I assigned  the value to.

My whole class:

```
var counterNumber = 0

@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

func initCount(){
    counterNumber = 0
}

func numberUp(){
    self.counterNumber++;
    counterLabel.text = "\(self.counterNumber)"
}

@IBAction func CountUp(sender: UIButton) {
    numberUp()
}

@IBAction func RestartButton(sender: UIButton) {
    initCount()
}


@IBAction func printButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.numberUp();
    print(self.counterNumber)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initCount()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Comment: **I have already done this and works 100%** Then what is the issue ?

Comment: "but it only prints out 0 because that's the default variable I assigned the value to." Basically I want to the print out the current value. It only shows 0 because that's the default value.

Comment: Then it means you are not increasing the value (counter) anywhere. You need to check the code where you handle the count button action

Comment: I have updated my code.

Comment: code is fine, it should work, now only one thing you need to check, check your IBActions bind with correct buttons. Remove all your IBActions bind with buttons and agin bind the relative actions. Because there may be a chance that reset and update both the actions binds on same button

Comment: That's the problem. Found out the restart and print were the same actions in one button. Appreciate the help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just call method `numberUp` in `printButton:` action.**

```
var counterNumber = 0//this is a variable of class
@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func printButton(sender: UIButton) {
    self.numberUp();
    print(self.counterNumber)
}

func numberUp(){
        self.counterNumber++;
        counterLabel.text = "\(self.counterNumber)"
    }
```

Comment: Tried that. Only prints "1" since the default is on 0 and the `numberUp()` method increments by 1

Comment: what will be output if you click next time ? or click more than one times

Comment: Just keeps printing "1"

Comment: Still getting "1" Do you want to see my whole class?

Comment: edit your question with full code of your viewcontroller

Comment: code is fine, it should work, now only one thing you need to check, check your IBActions bind with correct buttons. Remove all your IBActions bind with buttons and agin bind the relative actions. Because there may be a chanse that reset and update both the actions binds on same button

Comment: All It does is display "1" on the simulator and the output. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Found out the restart and print were the same actions in one button. Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **'self'** keyword to call instance variables.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Properties
    var counterNumber:Int = 0    // Make this variable Global to Class

    // IBOutlets Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func printButton(sender: UIButton) {
        self.numberUp()
        self.counterLabel.text = "\(self.counterNumber)"
        print("\n You Pressed ==> \(sender.title) button \(self.counterNumber) times")
    }

    func numberUp() {
        self.counterNumber += 1
        self.counterLabel.text = "\(counterNumber)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried that I got `You Pressed ==> Optional("Share Result") button 1 times` Do you want me to to post my whole class code within an edit of my post?